# What's wrong when entries appear again after save?

Tags: entries, control-panel

Entries should be live and say so in the CP, but they where gone in a listing in the frontend. But after saving entry by entry they appear again. What could be wrong?

Comment: Something caching related?  Either in the templates with the `{% cache %}` tag or do you have anything like Varnish or static caching on the site?

Comment: Hi Brad, Sorry for the late reaction. There are no cache tags around the items, so I guess not.

Comment: I think that using no cache tags doesn't means that there's no Varnish caching or static caching.

Did you checked with your hosting provider, or are you using caching plugins like Cache Monster or HTML cache?

How were these entries initially created: manually, or using an import plugin?

Comment: @romain Thanks for your participation. There's no Varnish or other caching systems active on the server. I do not use any cache plugins. And the content is added manualy.

Comment: How many entries do you have and how are them ordered in front end? Default limit of craft.entries is set to 100, and if you list is ordered by dateUpdated, that's perhaps why some entires are hidden until resaving?